# how can a label display string in multiple lines

Tags: swift, label, output

I have a label which displays a string triggered by a button and some int values entered in some textfields...

However, how can I make the label's string to be in multiple lines?

I can see a lot of people have asked this question, but for some reason, when I try to follow the answers it deletes the rest of my sentence after the use of "\n", as I have just tried earlier...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the label is created in storyboard, go to your storyboard and select it, then in the attribute inspector there is a field 'Lines' with default value of 1. change that 0 and that should work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following code

```
var label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10
    ,100, 300, 40));
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0);
label.text = "First label\nsecond line";
```

Also make sure the `height of label is enough to handle the string` when presented in multiline else it won't show the next line in label.

To calculate height of label according to String [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450434/figure-out-size-of-uilabel-based-on-string-in-swift) can be helpful

Comment: If I use your code, it does not respond at all when I hit my button. it just displays the string my page starts with.

Comment: you added this label in you view as self.view.addSubview(label);
also update the  frame of this label as per your requirement.