# Swift How to calculate one line text height from its font

Tags: ios, string, swift, height, uifont

I ran into an issue where I needed to animate translating a label vertically the same distance of a textField's text height. In most cases just `textField.bounds.heigt` but if the textField's height is bigger than the text height it will not be any good for me. So I need to know: 
**How to calculate the line height of the string text from its `UIFont`?**

Regarding the duplicate:
There's a little bit different of what I need. that answer(which I've referenced in my answer) get the total height depending on 1) the string 2) the width 3) the font. What I needed is **one line height dpending only on the font**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Figure out size of UILabel based on String in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450434/figure-out-size-of-uilabel-based-on-string-in-swift)

Comment: It's a little bit different of what I need. that answer(which I've referenced in my answer) get the total height depending on 1) the string 2) the width 3) the font. What I needed is **one line height dpending only on the font**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`UIFont` has a property `lineHeight`:

```
    if let font = _textView.font {
        let height = font.lineHeight
    }
```

where font is your font

Comment: font.lineHeight returns the height of a font. However, a UILabel is always a little higher than the line height

Answer (score 4):

I have been searching for a way to do that and find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30450559/1066762) where it has a `String` extension to calculate the size for the string and a given font. I have modified it to do what I want (**get the line height of text written using a font.**):

```
extension UIFont {
    func calculateHeight(text: String, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = text.boundingRect(with: constraintRect,
                                        options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                        attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: self],
                                        context: nil)
        return boundingBox.height
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone looking for it. (*may be myself in the future*).

Answer (score 0):

I've used this String extension in the past to draw some text as opposed to creating a UILabel somewhere. I don't like the fact that I can't seem to get the real height of the specific text I want to draw (not every string contains capital letters or characters with descenders, etc.) I've used a couple of enums for horizontal and vertical alignment around the given point. **Open to ideas on the vertical height.**

```
public func draw(at pt: CGPoint,
                 font: UIFont? = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12),
                 color: UIColor? = .black,
                 align: HorizontalAlignment? = .Center,
                 vAlign: VerticalAlignment? = .Middle)
{
    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [.font: font!,
                                                      .foregroundColor: color!]
    
    let size = self.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0),
                                 options: [ .usesFontLeading ],
                                 attributes: [ .font: font! ],
                                 context: nil).size
    var x = pt.x
    var y = pt.y
    if align == .Center {
        x -= (size.width / 2)
    } else if align == .Right {
        x -= size.width
    }
    if vAlign == .Middle {
        y -= (size.height / 2)
    } else if  vAlign == .Bottom {
        y -= size.height
    }
    let rect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    draw(in: rect, withAttributes: attributes)
}
```