# Swift: how to adapt UITableViewCell height to a UITextView inside it

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uitableview

Which is the simplest way both to adapt `UITextView` height to its content and then to adapt a `UITableViewCell` height, which acts as a container, to the same height of that `UITextView`?

Answer (score 2):

Set your UITextView number of line to 0.
In the viewDidLoad of your Controller that contains the tableView use :

```
 tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 55.0
 tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: If your text is large, you may have to use a higher number than 55 for the `estimatedRowHeight`.

Comment: Yeah this value depends of what you have in your UITableViewCell

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the height of your textview, i think you need to know the height of the text. So on your heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method, calculate the text height and return it using this:

```
func heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.max)

    let boundingBox = self.boundingRectWithSize(constraintRect, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)

    return boundingBox.height
}
```

You need to set the textview constrains, bottom, top, leading and trailing to 0, so they adjust to the size of the cell.
The code was taken [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30450559/4905076).