# How to count number of uicollectionview's rows in swift

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview

I need to determine uicollectionview's height.

```
let layout = contactCollectionView.collectionViewLayout
let heightSize = String(Int(layout.collectionViewContentSize.height))
```

The above solution works on some situations in my project. In this specific situation I need to count number of rows and then multiple it with a number to find height.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // height = (count rows) * 30 . every cell height is 30 
        // every cell has different width.
        return (presenter?.selectedContact.count)!
    }
```

**How can I find number of rows?**

**Update**

Look at the image.
[image]

This is my collectionView. Every cell has different width(because it is string). So It has different rows. The width of this collectionView is width of **view.frame**

Comment: You mean you want to find the scrollable height? Like the size of the whole content?

Comment: layout.collectionViewContentSize.height returns zero in this situation. Because the height of my stackView is zero and it can not compute height. I need to count the number rows, then multiple with a number to find whole content size.

Comment: So you want to know the height it *will* have after returning the 30, right?

Comment: Every cell height is 30. if It count rows. I can find height.

Comment: Then what's your question?

Comment: I need number of rows in a collectionView

Comment: How are you assigning values/content to the rows in the collectionView ? If you are using an array, you could simply use the count of the array.

Comment: @Sneha Please see update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compare if the `collectionView`'s `width` is greater than total previous width(s) then you increment rowCounts by one. I am assuming you are implementing `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` methods and per each cell you know the dynamic `width` at the moment. if you won't know the width at that moment, you can also calculate the `width` of `string` that would take with considering `UIfont` along with other stuff in each cell.

Here is a reference how to calculate the `width` of a `string` https://stackoverflow.com/a/30450559/6106583

Something like below

```
//stored properties 
var totalWidthPerRow = CGFloat(0)
var rowCounts = 0   
let spaceBetweenCell = CGFloat(10) // whatever the space between each cell is 


func collectionView(_collectionView:UICollectionView, layoutcollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
     
   let collectionViewWidth = view.frame.width 
   let dynamicCellWidth = //whatever you calculate the width 
   totalWidthPerRow += dynamicCellWidth + spaceBetweenCell
         

   if (totalWidthPerRow > collectionViewWidth) {
      rowCounts += 1
      totalWidthPerRow = dynamicCellWidth + spaceBetweenCell
   }

  return CGSizeMake(dynamicCellWidth , CGFloat(30))
}
```

Comment: This worked really for me with a few tweaks. Instead of using sizeForItemAt, I performed it in cellForItemAt where I could access each cells text width. I also started the rowCounts = 1, reset rowCounts and totalWidthPerRow when adding or subtracting new cells, and added a heightconstraint outlet from the collectionView which was made equal to rowCounts * rowHeight. Thanks Matt!