# how to find actual height of auto growable UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel, height, ios-autolayout

I have given number of lines to zero for UIlabel so that its height will adjust according its content.

sometimes If I give a big text it grows unto 4 lines in UI but when I access  its

> frame.size.height

it returns 21 instead of actual height which is way more bigger than that.

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: where you called this `frame.size.height` in didload or else

Comment: This could help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450434/figure-out-size-of-uilabel-based-on-string-in-swift

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I called it in viewdidload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

swift

```
public  static func requiredHeightForLabel(text : String, font : UIFont, width : CGFloat)   -> CGFloat {

    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))//UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, CGFloat.max))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text

    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height
}
```

objective c

```
+(CGFloat)getLabelHeightForString:(NSString *)string font:(UIFont *)font 
{
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(lablwidth, MAXFLOAT);

NSStringDrawingContext *context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];

CGSize boundingBox = [string boundingRectWithSize:size

                                          options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin

                                       attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}

                                          context:context].size;

size = CGSizeMake(ceil(boundingBox.width), ceil(boundingBox.height));

return size.width;

}
```

Comment: this give you exact height of the label according to text size

Comment: Thanks for sizetofit it helped me

Answer (score 1):

In your View Controller you can use method which notify you about layout finishing:

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        print("frame = \(label.frame)")
    }
```