# Unable to set height of UILabel/UITextView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitextview

I have an ViewController that has a title, an image and long text. I want it to be scrolled as a whole not the only text.

I am calculating the size according to its text. It is calculated correct but, I tried with that code.

```
newsDetailTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:newsDetailString.height(containerWidth: newsDetailTextView.frame.size.width)).isActive = true
```

Its size does not change.

What might be the wrong?

Could you please indicate me the way?

BR,

Erdem

Comment: `UILabel` and `UITextView` are different entities. One is for display, another is for input. In what scenario do you use them interchangeably?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Figure out size of UILabel based on String in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450434/figure-out-size-of-uilabel-based-on-string-in-swift)

Comment: Do you need the "long text" to be editable?

Answer (score 0):

Set scrollEnabled property of textView to false or uncheck via storyboard.

Comment: I did it, but no success.

Comment: @erdemgc create IBOuelet of height constraint and try setting the value accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically) if you want use a constraints way.

Check the Apple's official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html) in `Listing 13-1` where used heightAnchor.