# Textview is not scrolling vertically in the scrollview - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a view controller named as TeamDetailsViewController. I added scroll view to the view controller programmatically and added image view, nameLabel, and UITextview as the subview of the scroll view. imageview and NameLabel are showing up but Text View is not showing up for an unknown reason. Please help. Here is my code.

I am displaying set of items like table view using UIcolectionview. When a user taps on a single cell, he/she redirects to new view controller where the info about user like image, name, bio is displayed. Bio is `TextView`

```
class TeamDetailsController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViews()
        print(textView.text)
    }

    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let sv = UIScrollView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        sv.backgroundColor = .white
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sv.layer.borderWidth = 5
        return sv
    }()

    let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "team-tony")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()

    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Jared 'Donald' Dunn"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .bold)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let textView: UITextView = {
        var tv = UITextView()
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tv.textColor = .black
        tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        tv.isEditable = false
        return tv
    }()

    func setupViews() {

        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        scrollView.addSubview(profileImageView)
        profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true

        scrollView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        nameLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

        scrollView.addSubview(textView)
        textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true


    }

}
```

Comment: You need to add `bottomAnchor` of `textView` or need to set `textView` height.

Comment: @Kuldeep How to set dynamic height

Comment: set only bottomAnchor of textView.

Comment: @Pankil Can you tell me the code for bottom anchor. Should I set it to scrollview.bottomAnchor

Comment: Yes Try to set scrollView bottom to TextView `textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true`

Comment: @Pankil It's set now. But textview is scrolling horizontally. unable to scroll vertically

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the **bottomAnchor** of textView. Also you need to provide its height and width explicitly or set the **leadingAnchor** and **trailingAnchor**.

P.S. If this does not solve your problem. Please try to add more details in your question (A sample UI which you want develop).

Comment: I edited the code. Textview is showing up but it is scrolling horizontally. Please help. I want it to scroll vertically only.

Comment: You should use `UILabel` for the text you want to display. 
First calculate the height and width of Label by text you want to display. After that create a UILabel and add it to your scrollview. 
There is no need to add textview for displaying text only.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450434/figure-out-size-of-uilabel-based-on-string-in-swift/30450559
Check out this link on how to  **Figure out size of UILabel based on String in Swift**.