# How to set custom UIView width automatically based on its content?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I have a simple custom UIView (The view with white background on the screenshot) using xib and custom class derived from UIView.

[image: Custom view]

Inside I have a UILabel and a button on the same line ant that's all.

The size of the button is fixed.
The width of the label must be adjusted on its content.

What I would like is : 
- fit the size of the label to its content
- set the position of the button always just after the label
- fit the custom to its content

Like this :

[image: Correct Cutsom view]

How can I proceed to do this ?

**Add content :**

```
class Keyword: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super .init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super .init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

fileprivate func commonInit() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Keyword", owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.frame = self.bounds
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    let height = CGFloat(21)
    return CGSize(width: UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, height: height)
}

/*
// Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

}
```

UILabel contraints :

[image: UILabel contraints]

Tick UIButton constraints :

[image]

Comment: Use autolayout and intrinsic content size.

Comment: I try to use intrinsic content size, but it doesn't work

Comment: why negative vote its a genuine question ? I am voting up

Comment: This can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450434/figure-out-size-of-uilabel-based-on-string-in-swift

Comment: “I try to use intrinsic content size, but it doesn't work” what did you try? What didn’t work? That’s the way to do it, and it’s simple, so please show your code and your constraints under autolayout.

Comment: @matt I added code and constraints for details

Comment: Okay, so instead of `width: UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric`, the width needs to be based on the intrinsic widths of the label and the button. Note that you might need to invalidate when the label text changes.

Comment: auto layout is checked, but in fact intrinsicContentSize is never called. I'm trying to know why.

Comment: it works ! thanks @matt

Comment: @gduh Feel free to answer your own question, explaining your solution. Perfectly legal (and common) on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @matt, I found the solution.

There were just 2 errors in my code.

1. The following line code `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` in my custom view was missing, so `intrinsicContentSize`was never called.
2. As suggested by @matt, inside `intrinsicContentSize`, I need to provide a value based on the intrinsic widths of the label and the button for the width parameters instead of `UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric`

Now, the right code is :

```
class Keyword: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super .init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super .init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

fileprivate func commonInit() {
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Keyword", owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.frame = self.bounds
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    let height = btn.frame.size.height
    let width =  btn.frame.origin.x + btn.frame.size.width
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}


// Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following extension can be used to calculate the height and width of label.

```
extension String {

//Calculate height and width for label with string
func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], context: nil)

    return ceil(boundingBox.height)
}

func width(withConstrainedHeight height: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
    let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], context: nil)

    return ceil(boundingBox.width)
}

}
```

In your case, since the button size is fixed, you can calculate the width of label using the above extension and can be used to set the width constraint of the entire view. If your label has a leading constraint of 8 and a trailing constraint of 8 to the button and the button has a trailing constraint of 8 to the container view, then you can calculate the required width for your view as:

```
viewWidthConstraint.constant = 8+<width of string from the above extension>+8+<width of button>+8
```

Here the only changing parameter will be the width of the label.