# Swift tableView rows dynamic height not working

Tags: swift, uitableview, dynamic, height

Trying to get my messages in the tableView to have automatic height in each row but currently the long label texts are cut. Any help appreciated!

This function is called from viewDidLoad() and it is called for each row(tested with print):
[image]

All constraints are set in the storyboard:
[image]

Lines are set to 0:
[image]

Constraints for label:
[image]

Resulting in no dynamic height but cutting the message instead:
[image]

Comment: I personally suggest you that if you want performance then calculate cell height manually
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450434/figure-out-size-of-uilabel-based-on-string-in-swift

Comment: set label's content hugging priority to law value

Comment: and also set labels height constraints.constant to grater or equal to height of image view

Comment: I would remove the height constraint on the label and increase its content compression resistance priority.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue might be because your label is set in a UIView. What is your UIView constraint? Your UIView shouldn't have a height anchor for sure and maybe you could try setting it to the same height as your label. (Best guess)