# Is there no way to determine actual/correct NSString boundingRect height for any/random UIFont?

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, cgsize

I have tried everything I found on StackOverflow but nothing worked really.
I need to calculate boundingRect's **height** for **any/random** UIFont available.

The code is simple (I modified some of the code to be more readable):

```
let ps = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
ps.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
ps.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center
ps.lineSpacing = 0
ps.paragraphSpacingBefore = 0
ps.paragraphSpacing = 0

let myRandomFont = geMyRandomFont(name: randomFontName, size: myFontSize)
let attrParams = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: myRandomFont,
    NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: ps
    ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

let ns = NSString(string: text)
let toUseForDrawingBounds = ns.boundingRect(
    with: CGSize(width: boundsSize.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude),
    options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading],
    attributes: attrParams,
    context: nil
)
```

<strike>In rare cases (for some UIFonts) it works ok, but for most of the other fonts</strike> **toUseForDrawingBounds.height** is almost always 1 blank line too big.
(my input string **text** is always trimmed with **whitespacesAndNewlines**)

**EDIT 2:** After some testing I noticed this was not the case. With every UIFont (different combinations of font sizes & text) it can happen the returned height is 1 blank line too big. When I calculated number of lines (toUseForDrawingBounds.height / font.lineHeight) I clearly saw that sometimes returned number of lines was 1 too many.

I have tried tricks (StackOverflow) with (sizeToFit, etc.) UITextViews, UILabels, etc. Nothing really worked. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** To give a clear example, look at the attached image. Yellow rectangle approx. represents returned **toUseForDrawingBounds** bounds. I need proper bounds height so I can draw text vertically centered.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `NSString`? You should be using `String` with Swift.

Comment: Yes ok, but would that make any difference? I'll try with String.

Comment: The result is the same with String.

Comment: @sabiland - I seem to get reliable results using the extension(s) found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450434/figure-out-size-of-uilabel-based-on-string-in-swift ... you said *"In rare cases (for some UIFonts) it works ok, but for most of the other fonts"* --- can you list a couple specific Fonts that are giving you the incorrect heights?

Comment: I'll do some tests today and list some Ok-working fonts and Not-working fonts. Will also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450434/figure-out-size-of-uilabel-based-on-string-in-swift

Comment: Hmm but already second answer is this: "For multiline text this answer is not working correctly. " As you see I need multiline calculation, because my width is limited and. And I've also tried with UILabel sizeToFit, but I get almost exactly same (wrong) height.

Comment: @sabiland - are you trying to get the height so you can draw the text to an image?

Comment: I am trying to get height so I can later vertically-center drawn text. Because before that I calculate approx. optimal font-size (for any random UIFont (fontName)) for the visible area.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use **`size(withAttributes:)`** on `String` to get its `height` and `width`, i.e.

```
let text = "This is the sample text."
let textSize = text.size(withAttributes: [.font: myRandomFont, .paragraphStyle: ps])
print(textSize)
```

The above code is just an example of how you can proceed. Add the `attributes` as per your requirement.

Comment: I have already tried this, but this does not respect (ps.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping) wordWrapping. It returns height for a single line.

Comment: I mean my width is limited.

Answer (score 0):

Though I do not understand downvotes (because it is not trivial solution for any random font-name and random text combination), I have somehow managed to approx. solve my problem.

Just to summarize if anyone should have the same problems. I wanted to get an **optimal font-size** for **randomly chosen font-name** and **randomly chosen input text**
to be drawn inside specified **CGRect** (so, wordWrapped).

I did this like this:

1. For random font-name I took character **"W"** and with String.size(withAttributes:) and NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping I calculated maximum possible (binary search) fontSize to fit in CGRect
2. Then I checked if fontSize > CGRect.height (yes it can happen!) and reduced fontSize to CGRect.height (actually this 2 step solved almost all of my issues)
3. Then I just sqrt(pow(fontSize, 2) / numOfChars)) to get approx. optimal font-size to draw a text in a CGRect