# Expandable Label: Not working in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

For expanding label in UICollectionViewCell, I am using this [library](https://github.com/apploft/ExpandableLabel.git)

My code is as below:

```
label.delegate = self
label.shouldCollapse = true
label.numberOfLines = 4
label.collapsed = true

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

let size: CGSize = "Modern Furniture reflects the design ilosophy of form following function prevalent in modernism. These designs represent the ideals of cutting excess, practicality and an absence of decoration.".size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.font_light(14)])
            return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width , height: size.height + 390)

}
```

This thing works for UITableViewCell but it isn't working for UICollectionViewCell. In fact, the labels delegate methods are also not called.

Comment: I recommend you not to use library for this situation. just reload the collectionViewCell with new height and UILabel. less libraries = more stable code

Comment: @user1105951Can you please share the code?

Comment: google it. "self sizing cell" or you calculate the height of the string your self (recommended) . check start here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450434/figure-out-size-of-uilabel-based-on-string-in-swift