# UITextView contentSize is not update after paste swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextview

When I paste some text, textview height of contentSize is not correct. It returns text height before paste.

For example,

I expect height value : [contentSize Height] 1019 (after paste)
But real value : [contentSize Height] 540 (before paste)

I tried **setNeedDisplay()** method, but it's not working.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool
{
    print("[contentSize] \(textView.contentSize.height) size to fit \(textView.sizeThatFits(view.frame.size).height)")

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `textView(_:shouldChangeTextIn:replacementText:)` is called the text hasn't been applied to the view yet which means the contentSize has not changed. If possible, you can use `textViewDidChange(_:)`, it should print the correct size.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    print("[contentSize] \(textView.contentSize.height) size to fit \(textView.sizeThatFits(view.frame.size).height)")
}
```

If you really need to calculate the size of the text on the `shouldChangeTextIn` method, you could try calculating the size using an approach like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30450559/2217859).