# How to adjust the height of the textview depends on the content in correct way?

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried 2 more methods. But those are not giving me the correct solution.
**If i tried this one**

```
 func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        self.comments.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        self.comments.sizeToFit()
        self.comments.isScrollEnabled = false
    }
```

i can only type a one letter per a line.

**If i tried this one**

```
 func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
self.comments.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
self.comments.isScrollEnabled = false
let fixedWidth = passedOut.frame.size.width
let newSize = comments.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
comments.frame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
    }
```

Its working.
But at the viewDidLoad stage, the width of textview is certain less than which i constraints to the textview. But i gave the leading, trailing , height as same as passedOut textfield to that textview.

If i start typing in textview,[image: This image shown at viewDidLoad when i m using second method] the width of textview will become exact size which i want.

So pls suggest me what mistake i made?

Comment: Please use this solution instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69804957/2695502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Assign a height constraint to the text view
2. Use the following method to change the height:

   ```
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
       let size = textView.bounds.size
       let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(
        CGSize(width: size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
       )

       if size.height != newSize.height {
           self.userMessageTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = newSize.height
           textView.layoutIfNeeded()
       }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this behavior by doing 2 things in textview

1. Disable scrolling in textview
2. Assign the following constraints to textview

a) leading

b) trailing

c) top

d) height >= 30 ,assuming 30 is the minimum height of your textview.

Now when your text will grow textview will grow with it.

Comment: What an amazing way to solve that. . I had to test it to believe. It just worked...